# Why does this method keep returning dynamic despite the return type in the signature?

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic

So the type being returned by the activator (not shown here) is just a POCO that I created. Nothing special about it at all. But despite, the return type of `GetWrapper` or `GetWrapper<T>` the object being returned is of type dynamic so none of the properties of the actual class being return are being seen by intellisense. Any ideas?

[image]

UPDATE:
Sorry, Jon:

```
public static T GetWrapper<T>(object type, dynamic obj)
   where T : class, IRedditObject
{
    return GetWrapper(type, obj) as T;
}

public static object GetWrapper(object type, dynamic obj)
{
    return Activator.CreateInstance(Types[type.ToString()], obj);
}

public class LinkWrapper : IRedditObject
{
    private readonly dynamic _link;

    public string Kind { get { return "t3"; } }
    public dynamic Data { get { return _link.data; } }

    public LinkWrapper(dynamic link)
    {
        _link = link;
    }

    public string Domain { get { return Data.domain; } }
}

[TestMethod]
public void Test()
{
    var proxy = new SubredditProxy();
    var dotnet = proxy.GetSubredditAsync("dotnet").Result;

    var child1 = dotnet.data.children[0];

    // this is being returned as dynamic
    var obj = RedditDynamicObjectWrapperFactory.GetWrapper<LinkWrapper>(child1.kind, child1);


    Assert.IsNotNull(obj);
}
```

Comment: Please put your code in *text* in the question. It's very hard to read as-is. (A short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem wouldn't hurt, either. We don't know the type of `child1.kind` or `child1`.)

Comment: And the types of `child1` and `child1.kind`?

Comment: those are both dynamic. I'm pulling in a json result from reddit and deserializing as dynamic and then attempting to wrap them it in another object. This is pretty much it at this stage. The only part that's missing is `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(httpResultText);` which is the result of GetSubredditAsync

Comment: I updated the post to show the wrapper

Comment: Right - that's the problem then. See my answer :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I strongly suspect that either `child1` or `child1.kind` are of type `dynamic`, meaning that the expression is deemed to be a dynamically-bound expression, despite everything else.

Here's a short but *complete* example to demonstrate what I mean:

```
using System;

class Test
{
    public static T Foo<T>(object x)
    {
       return default(T);
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        object a = new object();
        dynamic b = a;

        var c = Foo<string>(a);
        var d = Foo<string>(b);

        Console.WriteLine(c.SomeRandomMember); // Invalid
        Console.WriteLine(d.SomeRandomMember); // Valid
    }
}
```

The invalid statement is invalid because the type of `c` is `string` - but the subsequent statement is fine, because the type of `d` is `dynamic`.

Even though there's only one possible method which it *could* be bound to at execution time - and even though that binding will always work - the basic rule is that almost *any* expression involving a `dynamic` value is deemed to be of type `dynamic`. (There are a few exceptions such as `as` and `new`.)

To make your return value non-dynamic, just cast your values to `object`:

```
var obj = RedditDynamicObjectWrapperFactory.GetWrapper<LinkWrapper>
     ((object) child1.kind, (object) child1);
```

That will now be a *statically* bound call. Or you could leave it as a dynamically bound call, and use the implicit conversion from an expression of type `dynamic` to other types:

```
LinkWrapper obj = RedditDynamicObjectWrapperFactory.GetWrapper<LinkWrapper>(child1.kind, child1);
```

Comment: Interesting. Ok, so I also noticed that if I ditch `var` then the cast takes hold correctly

Comment: @Sinaesthetic: Yes - see the end of my answer. You're basically making the call dynamically at that point, but then asking the compiler to convert `dynamic` to the right type at the end. I prefer the "cast before call" approach so that as much of your code is statically bound as possible, but that's a personal preference.

Comment: ^^ you updated your post right as I posted that lol. nice. great, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the current answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/25586620/1942762) but here is the explanation from the the C# programming guide ([Overload resolution with arguments of type dynamic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/using-type-dynamic#overload-resolution-with-arguments-of-type-dynamic)):

> Overload resolution occurs at run time instead of at compile time if one or more of the arguments in a method call have the type dynamic, or if the receiver of the method call is of type dynamic.

Your parameter is probably of type dynamic so your IDE will consider `obj` as a dynamic too