# Why does a method that returns a type result in an implicit typing of dynamic?

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic

In the following code snippet why does the implicitly typed variable be determined as a `dynamic` instead of the method's return type of `FluentClass`?

```
public static class DynamicTest
{
    public class FluentClass
    {
        public FluentClass SomeMethod(dynamic arg)
        {
            return this;
        }
    }
    public static void Main()
    {
        dynamic data = new { Data = 1 };

        var fluentClass = new FluentClass();
        // fluentClass variable is typed FluentClass
        var methodResult = fluentClass.SomeMethod(data);
        // methodResult variable is typed dynamic
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you know it's typed as dynamic?

Comment: VS intellisense shows that its treated as a dynamic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why does a method that returns a type result in an implicit typing of dynamic?

Because that's the best the compiler can do, given the information it has.

The reason `methodResult` is `dynamic` is that the entire expression used to initialize it is `dynamic`. And that's the case, because `data` is dynamic.

When you use `dynamic`, you're telling the compiler to not resolve types at compiler time. Instead, they should be resolved according to the normal compiler rules, but at run-time.

The `fluentClass` variable could hold some implementation of `FluentClass` that contains an overload that matches the run-time type of the argument `data`. In that case, a different implementation of `SomeMethod()` could be called, returning a different type.

You've told the compiler to defer type resolution to run-time, so it can't force things back into a strongly-typed context unless you tell it explicitly what type things are. In your example, it can't, so the type remains `dynamic`.

Note that you might have thought that the compiler would identify the one overload you've provided, based on its parameter type of `dynamic`. But that's not how `dynamic` works. The `dynamic` parameter affects only the implementation of the method, i.e. the code in its body. As far as calling the method goes, the parameter is essentially `object`. It's just that when the parameter value is *used* in the method body, it has the features of `dynamic`.

Another way to think of `dynamic` is that it accepts any object as input (like `object`), but then allows you to use any member of that object that you believe exists (if it doesn't exist an exception will be thrown at run-time). Using `dynamic` defers the compiler logic downstream, i.e. for the output of any usages of the `dynamic` variable, but doesn't affect the *input*, i.e. the assignment of that variable.

Note also that even if the method call is completely unambiguous, e.g. a `static` method where there's only one method with that name, you'll still get a `dynamic` result. Once you start using `dynamic`, it sticks with you until you provide an explicit cast to get back to a known type.

Related reading:

Very similar to your question, if not actually duplicates:
[Why does a method invocation expression have type dynamic even when there is only one possible return type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9382130)
[Why does this method keep returning dynamic despite the return type in the signature?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25586520)
[Why doesn't this string.Format() return string, but dynamic?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35366650)

More general discussion of `dynamic`:
[What is the 'dynamic' type in C# 4.0 used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2690623)
[C# 4: Real-World Example of Dynamic Types](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2255982)

Comment: I think the thing that makes this super confusing, in the case of Visual Studio, is that using F12/"Go To Definition" on the method still brings it to the "overload" that returns a concrete type.  To me, the TL;DR here is your paragraph "The fluentClass variable could hold some implementation of FluentClass that contains an overload that matches the run-time type of the argument data. In that case, a different implementation of SomeMethod() could be called, returning a different type."  That was the one quick realization I was looking for.